# Multiple product model rewrites

Tags: product, module, magento-1, overrides, model

I have two custom modules: ModuleA and ModuleB.

Each one rewrites Core Product Model via:

```
<global>
    <models>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <product>AD_ModuleA_Model_Product</product>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
    </models>
</global>
```

and class header: `class AD_ModuleA_Catalog_Model_Product extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`

and

```
<global>
    <models>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <product>AD_ModuleB_Model_Product</product>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
    </models>
</global>
```

and class header: `class AD_ModuleB_Catalog_Model_Product extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`

but AFAIK, it's not correct syntax since Magento doesn't support multiple rewrites in such case. I've put debugging line `Mage::log('AD_ModuleB_Catalog_Model_Product file has been loaded')` before its class definition, but it even doesn't load a class file.

Is there another way to extent Core Product Model in multiple independent custom models?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step:Don't used two module to overwrite class

- Merge the code from one conflicting file into another and switch off
  the rewrite config.xml in one
- Switch off the rewrite in one config.xml and then make the
  conflicting extension PHP file extend the other extension
- Use the  capability to make one extension depend on another.
  They will then rewrite in that order

try this

```
class AD_ModuleA_Catalog_Model_Product extends AD_ModuleB_Catalog_Model_Product
```

seemore:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14815717/multiple-modules-overriding-same-core-file-in-magento

http://www.webshopapps.com/blog/2010/11/resolving-magento-extension-conflicts/

**Edit:**

**Step1:** modify `AD_ModuleA.xml` which is `depends on module AD_ModuleB` module.`AD_ModuleA.xml` code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <AD_ModuleA>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
       <depends><AD_ModuleB/></depends> <!-- depends on module ModuleB -->
        </AD_ModuleA>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**Step2:** `AD_ModuleB.xml` depends on `Mage_Catalog` module

AD_ModuleB.xml code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <AD_ModuleB>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        <depends><Mage_Catalog/></depends> <!-- depends on module Mage_Catalog  -->
        </AD_ModuleB>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**Step3:**  Remove write code from  rewrite code AD_ModuleB module config.xml

```
<global>
    <models>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <product>AD_ModuleB_Model_Product</product>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
    </models>
</global>
```

**Step4:** change rewrite class code

```
class AD_ModuleA_Model_Product extends  AD_ModuleB_Model_Product
```

and

```
class  AD_ModuleB_Model_Product extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
```

**Step5:** class `AD_ModuleB_Catalog_Model_Product` class is wrong but you was define it should be

```
AD_ModuleB_Model_Product
```

http://blog.belvg.com/get-ready-for-magento-certified-developer-exam-describing-methods-for-resolving-module-conflicts.html

Comment: What if ModuleA and ModuleB are owned by different authors?

Comment: it not depend on author .more study http://blog.belvg.com/get-ready-for-magento-certified-developer-exam-describing-methods-for-resolving-module-conflicts.html

Comment: Can't make it working. What exactly should I write on config.xmls of ModuleA and ModuleB?

Comment: Why `AD_ModuleB_Catalog_Model_Product` class is wrong? My directory structure is AD\ModuleB\Catalog\Model\Product.php

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table

Answer (score 0):

Open the moduleB class.

Change

`class AD_ModuleB_Catalog_Model_Product extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`

with

`class AD_ModuleB_Catalog_Model_Product extends AD_ModuleA_Catalog_Model_Product`

that's all (in most cases).